How to "Clamp" one unit vector between two others?
Assuming a 3D cartesian space, imagine:

I have two unit vectors A and B that are not colinear
I have a third unit vector C that I wish to "clamp" between A and B on the surface of the unit sphere

By "clamp" I mean I want to ensure that C lies on the shortest geodesic around the unit sphere surface created between A and B.
If it lies outside the shortest geodesic, I would like to find the nearest point on that geodesic (e.g. the point on that geodesic that is the shortest path around the surface from C).
How can I calculate that?

Please edit for clarity.  What do you mean by "clamp"?

Seems like projecting C onto the plane spanned by A and B, then extending that line until it intersects the sphere, would give you the closest point on the great circle to the tip of C.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I tried to rewrite it to be more obvious, but I'm not sure exactly how I can make it clearer.

@MatthewLeingang That would give me the closest point on the great circle, but I need the closest point specifically on the geodesic formed between A and B (which is part of that circle but not all of it).

Following up on @MatthewLeingang's comment: there are generally two geodesics between two points (one can also go the long way around back, speaking colloquially). You will have to specify what you want to do if C "points the opposite direction" from A and B, and is thus closer to the longer geodesic.

@JonathanZ thank you, I've edited the question to clarify that.

Do I understand correctly that if $C$ is closer to the longer geodesic, you want whichever of $A$ and $B$ is closer to $C$?

This might be a lot more irregular than you expected, but there's not going to be a simple clean formula. Expect a lot of if statements if you're coding this.
Okay, first we need to set up a coordinate system in the plane spanned by $A$ and $B$. Set $$ \vec x = A.$$
Next, we need a vector perpendicular  to  $\vec x$ that lies on the same side as $B$. Set
$$\vec y_0 = B-(B \cdot A)A$$
$$ \vec y = \vec y_0/ \|\vec y_0\|$$
So $A$ is has an angle of $0$ ($\theta_A = 0$), and the angle of $B$ (let's call it $\theta_B$) is $\arccos(B \cdot A)$, which you should make sure is somewhere in $(0, \pi)$, i.e. the most common principal value range.
Now we project $C$ into the plane spanned by $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ (it probably won't lie on the unit circle, but that's okay), and find the angle for it
$$ \theta_C = \operatorname{atan2}( C\cdot \vec y, C \cdot \vec x)$$
If $\theta_C \in [\theta_A, \theta_B]$, then $C$ is closest to a point that lies along the shortest geodesic between $A$ and $B$, and your answer is
$$\cos(\theta_C)\vec x +\sin(\theta_C)\vec y$$
(Note that this is the same answer that @MatthewLeingang's comment would give you much more simply, but we'll use the extra machinery here to handle the cases where $C$ doesn't lie in this nice range.)
If $\theta_C \not \in [\theta_A, \theta_B]$, then you have to figure out which "endpoint" it's closest to, $A$ or $B$, and that's your answer. The angle we have to compare $\theta_C$ against is the one opposite the angle halfway between $A$ and $B$, i.e.
$$\theta_{mid} = (\theta_A + \theta_B)/2 - \pi$$
The comparison isn't straight-forward, as we're dealing with angles, but $\theta_{mid}$ is guaranteed to be in quadrant III, so I'm leaving that bit for you to deal with.
